# Wordpress: Moving inline images to Featured Galleries

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

Here's my situation:

I'm redesigning an existing Wordpress site.

The new design separates all images from the actual post content and puts it in a [Featured Gallery](http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/featured-galleries).

Currently, each post has your typical inline images in the post content.

Is this even remotely possible to extract all inline images from the post content, and create Featured Galleries with those images for each post?

In the past I've done something like the below to grab the first image in the post content, and set it as the standard featured image, but nothing like what I have to do with this dilemma.

```
function wpforce_featured() {
      global $post;
      $already_has_thumb = has_post_thumbnail($post->ID);
          if (!$already_has_thumb)  {
          $attached_image = get_children( "post_parent=$post->ID&post_type=attachment&post_mime_type=image&numberposts=1" );
                      if ($attached_image) {
                            foreach ($attached_image as $attachment_id => $attachment) {
                            set_post_thumbnail($post->ID, $attachment_id);
                            }
                       }
                    }
  }  //end function
  add_action('the_post', 'wpforce_featured');
  add_action('save_post', 'wpforce_featured');
  add_action('draft_to_publish', 'wpforce_featured');
  add_action('new_to_publish', 'wpforce_featured');
  add_action('pending_to_publish', 'wpforce_featured');
  add_action('future_to_publish', 'wpforce_featured');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the method I used was to create a one time script that I ran to move all inline images from the post to the Featured Gallery, like this:

```
// Loop over every post

while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();    

    // Get the images attached to the post.

    $imageids = array();

    $images = get_attached_media( 'image', $post->ID );

    foreach ($images as $image) {
        $imageids[] = $image->ID;
    }

    $comma_separated = implode(",", $imageids);

    // Save them to the Featured Gallery (Got this info by digging into the Featured Gallery plugin's source code)

    if ( $post->post_type == 'revision' ) {return;}
    if ( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'fg_perm_metadata', FALSE ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'fg_perm_metadata', $comma_separated );
    } else {
        add_post_meta( $post->ID, 'fg_perm_metadata', $comma_separated );
    }
    if ( !$comma_separated ) delete_post_meta( $post->ID, 'fg_perm_metadata' );

endwhile;

// Reset Query

wp_reset_query();
```

Then, I created a function that removes all images in the post content, which I placed in functions.php:

```
function remove_images( $content ) 
{
    $content =
        preg_replace(
            array('{<a(.*?)(wp-att|wp-content\/uploads)[^>]*><img}',
                '{ wp-image-[0-9]*" /></a>}'),
            array('<img','" />'),
            $content
        );
    $content = preg_replace('/<img(.*)>/i','', $content, 1);
    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'remove_images' );
```

First `preg_replace` removes the link around the images. Second removes the image.

Comment: So I'm commenting on this a year and a half later, I realize. However, just found this and wanted to say, as the author of Featured Galleries, and this solution is great. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is if i read you correctly is that all the images are located as urls in the post content?

You can parse them:

```
$content = get_the_content();
$html = new DOMDocument;
$html->loadHTML($content);

//get the images
$images = $html->getElementsByTagName('img');

foreach($images as $image=>$key {
     $imageurls[]=$key->attributes->getNamedItem("src")->value;//play with this cant remember how it returns object.
}

$content= preg_replace('/<img(.*)>/i','',$content,1);

echo $content; 

// you also have a array of images to use.
```

Comment: So I would basically have to build a custom file in order to run once, and put this code in a loop that loops over every single post. Oh and add the actual code that creates a Featured Gallery and attaches it to the post. The last part is the part I'm the most confused about.

Comment: your overcomplicating this. id suggest wrap the above in 2 functions (1 for the parser to get your images and add the gallery html and js) and the 2nd for the preg replace to remove the images from the content so its not appearing twice. then instead of using the_content in single.php use your custom functions. other than that you can hook into pre-get-posts and modify the_content into a complete html string including your gallery.